# Updating chart.js in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web

I want to create a chart by add labels and data from an API and update this one.

I create a method **addData()** in charts.component.ts that looks in this way:

```
 addData(chart, labels_builds,labels_data){
     chart.data.labels.push(labels_builds);
     chart.data.datasets.data.forEach(dataset => {
        dataset.data.push(labels_data);
     });
     chart.update();
 }
```

This will be call here:

```
getMisraLintChart(projectVariantId: number,filterType : string, filterValue: string): void {
    this.chartService.getMisraLintChart(projectVariantId, filterType, filterValue)
    .subscribe(pageChart =>{
        this.chartMisraLint = pageChart
      this.addData(this.myChart,pageChart.build,pageChart.data);
        })
    }
```

In **ngOnInit()** i have this code:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getFilters();

   var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
   this.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
       labels: [],
       datasets: [{
           label: '# of Total Messages',
           data: [],
          backgroundColor:'#ffe4c9',

       }]
   },
   options: {
       scales: {
           yAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                   beginAtZero:true,

               }
               ,
               scaleLabel: {
                 display: true,
                  labelString: 'Total Messages'
               }
           }]
           ,
           xAxes: [{
             scaleLabel: {
               display: true,
                labelString: 'Builds'
             }
           }]
       }
   }
});
```

**I get the error :ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.**

If anyone could push me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `chart.data.datasets.data.forEach()` data seems to be undefined I guess

Comment: Do you want a chart based on API data, and update chart if data changes?

Comment: Should it be `chart.data.datasets.forEach`? Because you have named the  parameter as `dataset`

Comment: Yes. I want a chart based on API data and it should be updated based on the data it receives.

Comment: I put chart.data.datasets.forEach and i don't see the error anymore but my chart doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you receive this error because you never initialized this.myChart.data.datasets.data before looping over it. You've only typed it. You could fix that by setting a default array, like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getFilters();

   var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
   this.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
       labels: [] = [] // might as well,
       datasets: [{
           label: '# of Total Messages',
           data: [] = [], // <== note this part, the initialization
          backgroundColor:'#ffe4c9',

       }]
   },
   options: {
       scales: {
           yAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                   beginAtZero:true,

               }
               ,
               scaleLabel: {
                 display: true,
                  labelString: 'Total Messages'
               }
           }]
           ,
           xAxes: [{
             scaleLabel: {
               display: true,
                labelString: 'Builds'
             }
           }]
       }
   }
});
```

That being said, I am pretty sure this will not resolve your functional goal. I am pretty sure you don't want to add result elements from the server call based on the items already there; but just want to add them all. You're frankly looping the wrong data. So you'll also have to change the addData method. Like this:

```
addData(chart, 
        labels_builds = [], // See comment below
        labels_data = [] // added this as an alternative null check for your server data.
){
     chart.data.labels = [
        ...chart.data.labels, // Check the ES6 spread operator, you'll like it.
        ...labels_builds      // In essence in this case it means "every element of"
     ];
     chart.data.datasets.data = [
        ...chart.data.datasets.data,
        ...labels_data
     ];
     chart.update();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! ES6 spread operator is so nice. The Xaxis looks oke from API data but Yaxis does not receive anything. In this form "...chart.data.datasets.data, ...labels_data"  I get  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined.

Comment: Then you most likely didn't use the whole answer; since either your labels_data or chart.data.labels is undefined; and my full solution provided both with defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    updateChart() {
    //first set datasets length 0
    this.chart.data.datasets.length = 0;
    //call update method
    this.chart.update();

    const color = Chart.helpers.color;
    //define your data here
    let data1 = {
        labels: ['1 Jan', '2 Jan', '3 Jan', '4 Jan', '5 Jan', '6 Jan', '7 Jan'],
        datasets: [
            {
                fill: false,
                borderWidth: 3,
                backgroundColor: color(this.layoutConfigService.getConfig('colors.state.brand')).alpha(0.6).rgbString(),
                borderColor: this.layoutConfigService.getConfig('colors.state.primary'),
                label: 'Value1',
                pointStyle: 'line',
                pointHoverRadius: 4,
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 12,
                pointBackgroundColor: Chart.helpers.color('#000000').alpha(0).rgbString(),
                pointBorderColor: Chart.helpers.color('#000000').alpha(0).rgbString(),
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: this.layoutConfigService.getConfig('colors.state.primary'),
                pointHoverBorderColor: Chart.helpers.color('#000000').alpha(0.1).rgbString(),

                data: [this.getNo(), this.getNo(), this.getNo(), this.getNo(), this.getNo(),this.getNo(),this.getNo()]
            }
        ]
    };
    //asign data1 to chart data
    this.chart.data = data1;
    //again update chart
    this.chart.update();
}
getNo() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 100 ) + 1);
}
```

This worked for me...!